# Computed Ember Property without setter does not update

Tags: ember.js

When I have an computed property that is setting himself and then change a dependency, why is the property not reloading?

The data property function is only called once, but why is it not updating after setting the filter?

```
var fetch = function(filter) {
  return new Em.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve(filter ? "OK" : "NOT OK");
  });
};

MyType = Em.Object.extend({
  filter: null,
  data: function() {
    console.log("refresh data");
    var self = this;
    fetch(self.get('filter')).then(function(data) {
      self.set('data', data);
    });
    return null;
  }.property('filter')
});

console.log("start");

var x = MyType.create();

console.log(x.get('data'));

Em.run.later(function() {
  console.log(x.get('data'));
}, 0);

Em.run.later(function() {
  x.set('filter', true);
}, 50);

Em.run.later(function() {
  console.log(x.get('data'));
}, 100);
```

The produced output:

```
 "start"
"refresh data"
null
"NOT OK"
"NOT OK"
```

But the expected output:

```
 "start"
"refresh data"
null
"NOT OK"
"OK"
```

demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/korecamu/1/edit

Comment: You always return `null` from the property function, will mean it's always going to be `null`...

Comment: @GJK: no, the output is always the first result of the Promise returned by fetch. I've added that to the question.